# Custom git credential helper fails to authenticate on windows

Tags: windows, git

I have a custom credential helper executable written in C++ on Windows 10. It basically just std::couts the username and password with endl:

```
std::cout << "username=myuser" << std::endl;
std::cout << "password=mypassword" << std::endl;
```

The credential helper gets registered:

```
[credential "https://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git"]
     helper = C:/Users/myuser/helper/GitCredentialManager.exe
```

The credential helper is called but fails to authenticate for the remote (I tested github and gitlab)

```
remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git'
```

2FA is disabled and I also tried to provide an access token instead of a password.

I also tried to use printf instead of std::cout. I called std::cout.flush()
Is there anything that I am doing wrong / do I miss any windows particularities? 
*This works perfectly fine on macOS*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows I had to add the null terminator to make it work.

```
std::cout << "username=myuser\0" << std::endl;
std::cout << "password=mypassword\0" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the protocol line, as seen in the "[Under the Hood](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage#_under_the_hood)" section.

```
$ git credential fill (1)
protocol=https (2)
host=mygithost
(3)
protocol=https (4)
host=mygithost
username=bob
password=s3cre7
```

> Git-credential is then waiting for input on stdin. We provide it with the things we know: the protocol and hostname.
>
> A blank line indicates that the input is complete, and the credential system should answer with what it knows.

But don't forget you also have the [Microsoft Git Credential Manager for Mac and Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux), which would handle all that in a secure way.

Comment: I've added both: protocol and host to stdout but no luck. I checked with GIT_TRACE=1 to see that I am getting called twice, once with get and then with erase - I guess because git believes the credentials were wrong. The error remains the same: Invalid username or password